# XCode 4 active architecture setting

Tags: xcode4, armv6

I've updated the XCode to the latest 4 version (final). My project depends on a 3rd party library that was build for armv6.

The problem is that i can not change the "active architecture" as it was in 3.x.x instead I see that during linking the active architecture flag is always passed as armv7.

Does anyone know how to set active architecture for the build target (or for scheme) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to myself ...

Yes and no. You can not change the arc but you can trick the Xcode. Set it to compile not only for active architecture and leave only archv6 in the list. Hope it helps to whoever looks for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible to change the *Architecure* settings in Xcode 4. Select the project file in the Project Navigator. Then select the target you like to build. Then select build settings->All->Levels. In the search box enter "architectures". You should see the *Architectures* and *Build Active Architecture* settings.

Comment: Well, its not what I asked. Prior to XCode 4 there was a setting of active (current) architecture, which is not related to valid architectures in the target settings nor to architectures settings. It's an attribute that is being passed to the linker.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve that issue? I found the same problem with one of my older projects that was developed with xCode3 but now in xCode4 i have the very same issue. Thanks