# Updating the ios5 app (nib files) to support ios6

Tags: ios, iphone-5, armv7

Recently I am facing an issue updating my ios5 application which is running fine in ios5 to run in iPhone 5 (ios6). The app has nib files, which need to be re arranged according to respective bounds of the view. When build/run in the simulator works fine, but when tried in the device, gives error regarding the architecture.

Checked these links

[XCode 4 active architecture setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369569/xcode-4-active-architecture-setting)

[What Xcode settings should I use to support both armv6 and armv7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447349/what-xcode-settings-should-i-use-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7?rq=1)

Changed the 'Build Active ARchitecture' to YES/ NO -but no use
Changed the 'Valid Architecture' to 'armv6 armv7', 'armv6', 'standard armv6' etc. but no luck

If it runs in iPhone5, it did not run in other devices, iPad (ios 5.1.1) and iPod (ios 5.1.1)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: armv6 is not longer supported by iOS 6, just make sure that you deployment target is set to iOS 5.

Comment: @rckoenes, is there a way for an application to support the latest and old versions of ios? ios - 4.0, 5.0 and 6.0

Comment: Yes, you set the deployment to iOS 4.3 (latest version you can support with ARMv7) and set the base SDK to 6. Just make sure that you do not call any methods or classes that are not supported by running version of iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: In plist file i have made below changes]                                              After lot many hours got the solution for this. I have changed like this in plist it's getting started. Thank you..

Comment: seems like we have to mention the entry point (MainWindow)to the application for all the devices. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0):

Use armv7 and armv7s (unless you have conflict with 3rd party code) for the valid architectures.  iPhone 5 will run armv7 code as well as armv7s.  XCode 4.5 dropped support for armv6.

Here are a couple of related SO questions that might help you.

[What is armv7s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569339/what-is-armv7s)

http://wanderingcoder.net/2012/09/16/no-armv7s-til-tested/

[image: Valid Architectures Image]

Comment: I tried like this as well, it's giving armv7s architecture not supported your machine error. I will try again. Thank you  @EIJay

Comment: You don't have to include armv7s.  I have projects that do not include that architecture and they run just fine on iPhone 5.

Comment: When i am using arvm7 it's working in iPhone5, But it's giving problem in iPod and iPhone4. Any other place i need to change settings?